# IIS 7.5 and ASP .NET 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0, iis-7.5

Are there any known issues with IIS 7.5? I'm getting the following error when I try to browse/start/view any page on the site.

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration
 data for the page is invalid.

Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    BeginRequest
Handler Not yet determined
Error Code  0x80070021
Config Error    This configuration section cannot be used at this path. 
 This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by
default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with 
  overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false". 

Config Source
97:         </modules>
98:         <handlers>
99:             <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
```

Comment: What kind of application is it? Web Site, Web Application Project? Web Service? How did you publish it? What version of .NET is installed on the system, and what OS and version is it?

Comment: Project Type = Website running in IIS 7.5
.NET FX = 3.5 SP1
OS = Windows 7

Comment: And how did you publish the web site to IIS?

Comment: This is my local/dev machine. I just added a new site, then added it to my solution in VS 2008

Answer (score 18):

Had a similar issue, ended up finding this article of use:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942055

basically the applicationHost.config had the handler section locked:
was

```
<section name="handlers" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
```

i changed it to

```
<section name="handlers" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

and it worked.

also worth checking that ALL the asp.net roles have been installed, see [link text](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731252(WS.10).aspx).

Comment: Yep, ASP.NET uses a hierarchy of configuration files, starting from the folder closest to the requested page, down to the application root, and then into the .NET Framework Config folder - there are two or three in there that work together, down to machine.config. Elements can be locked at any of those levels, see both: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.allowoverride.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.overridemodedefault.aspx

Comment: "also worth checking that ALL the asp.net roles have been installed, see link text." ASP.NET was not enabled and I received a HTTP 500.19 error. The link (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731252%28WS.10%29.aspx) was the answer. Thank you thank you thank you x 10

Answer (score 5):

[This](http://blog.laksha.net/2009/08/http-error-50019-internal-server-error.html) has solved my issue on Windows 7 64bit IIS 7.

Comment: This was the issue for me. I was on Windows 7 - 64 bit as well. Thanks Aboo.

Answer (score 2):

Using a text editor such as Notepad, open the `applicationHost.config` file in the following location:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
```

Basically, the `applicationHost.config` had the handler section locked. It was

```
<section name="handlers" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
```

changed it to

```
<section name="handlers" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

and it works.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the majority of people receiving this error did not select enough check boxes in the iis feature selection in "Programs and Features" in the control panel's install.

Terrible error reporting IMO.

Comment: heh, I figured this would help someone *sooner* than later ;)

Answer (score 1):

The last answer gave me the answer, then it gave me another error, so you should check [this](http://www.rileytech.net/post/2008/01/21/Vista-IIS7-Windows-Authentication-and-you.aspx) one too

Answer (score 1):

This is comming due to asp.net not install in IIS for this,
Turn on Windows features on or off, iis feature selection in "Programs and Features" in the control panel's. Select IIS then "world wide web services"
then "Application Devlopment Features" then "ASP" and "ASP.NET"

Answer (score 0):

After fixing as above said We will get the following error

> Error message when you visit a Web site that is hosted on IIS 7.0:
>   HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden.

To resolve this problem, use one of the following methods.

---

Method 1:To resolve this problem, follow these steps:

- Start IIS Manager. To do this, click Start, click Run, type inetmgr.exe, and then click OK.
- In IIS Manager, expand server name, expand Web sites, and then click the Web site that you want to modify.
- In Features view, double-click Directory Browsing.
- In the Actions pane, click Enable.

---

Method 2: To resolve this problem, follow these steps:

- Start IIS Manager. To do this, click Start, click Run, type inetmgr.exe, and then click OK.
- In IIS Manager, expand server name, expand Web sites, and then click the Web site that you want to modify.
- In Features view, double-click Default Document.
- In the Actions pane, click Enable.
- In the File Name box, type the name of the default document, and then click OK.

Comment: IMO, Method 1 is a security risk and should never be used on public facing websites. Instead, provide permissions to the application pool identity (either IUSR or user of your choice) to access the underlying file/folders. To do this, right click on the web application node and select edit permissions.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

This also happens if the .Net Framework Version is not correct or the Managed Pipeline Mode is not set properly.

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same error. This solved my issue
http://blog.laksha.net/2009/08/http-error-50019-internal-server-error.html